# Calling dynamic strings from ListMap

Tags: scala

I have some nested ListMaps containing strings. For some of these strings though I would like to return the current time. I am new to scala, but I feel like the language is built around this "function as a variable" theme, that this should be possible. So far I have the code below, however it evaluates at definition, whereas I would like it to evaluate each time the value is read.

```
val sql_dynamic = ListMap("user_history_create_date" -> 
    {(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).format(new Date())},
    "fan_history_create_time" -> 
    {(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")).format(new Date())});
```

I've tried various syntax in attempts to make these anonymous functions "defines", but have only managed compile errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
val sql_dynamic = ListMap("foo" -> (() => new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date())))
println(sql_dynamic.get("foo").get.apply())
```

Here, I'm adding a `Function0[String]` as the value to the map and it will only be applied when I get it out and explicitly apply it

**EDIT**
In response to your comment, it's a bad idea to put values into the map that do not belong to some common type.  You could solve that by doing something like this:

```
trait DateString{
  def date:String
}

case class StaticDateString(date:String) extends DateString

class FunctionDateString(func:() => String) extends DateString{
  def date = func()
}

object DateTest{
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val sql_dynamic = ListMap(
        "foo" -> new FunctionDateString(() => new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date())),
        "bar" -> StaticDateString("2013-01-01")
      )
      println(sql_dynamic.get("foo").get.date)  
      println(sql_dynamic.get("bar").get.date)  
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is pretty close to what I want to do. The only thing is I am looking through this ListMap where other values are static Strings, so I can't call .get.apply() on those. From what I understand, this is where match{} can be useful. You mentioned that this new code returns a Function0[String], so I changed my for loop to return [String,Object] and wrote this:val sv = v match {
       case s: String => s
       case f: Function0[String] => f.get.apply()
      }

Comment: However I get two compile errors. One says : non-variable type argument String in type pattern () => String is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure. The other says: value get is not a member of () => String
[error]                                                         case f: Function0[String] => f.get.apply()

Comment: Yeah I agree its not a good idea. 99% of the time it is going to be static though and there would be a huge amount of refactoring and there is only one edge case where I would have to read it.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the `def` keyword:

`def` defines a **function** (or a method if you are in the body of a class)
`val` defines a **constant**
`var` defines a **variable**

As you can see in this example functions are evaluated at each call:

```
scala> def fun = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
fun: java.util.Date

scala> println(fun)
Fri Jun 21 19:33:12 CEST 2013

scala> println(fun)
Fri Jun 21 19:33:14 CEST 2013
```